Не работает Metasploit в Kali Linux
У меня не работает metasploit, что бы я не делал. Впервые установив kali на VirtualBox, сразу опробовал metasploit (на тот момент он ещё работал) и забыл о нём. Через время, скачал ruby для изучения, с этого момента metasploit стал выдавать ошибки при запуске.
Я переустановил VirtualBox и kali, но ничего не поменялось. В придачу, после переустановки kali, у меня остались утилиты которых нету изначально (hping3 и arping).

